# firestore is adding data twice and is not letting me have UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am trying to find a way in which I can add the data once on firestore but it keeps adding the data twice with different unique ID, and also I am having trouble finding a way to input the user UID as a "doc ID"

here is my code which adds the data twice with different UNIQUE IDs and not the user.uid

```
   registerBtn.addEventListener('click' , e => {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        db.collection("users").add({
          FirstName: firstName,
          Middle_Name: middleName,
          Last_Name: lastName,
          Email: email,
      })

      console.log('data successfully added');

      } else {
        console.log('something went wrong');
      } 
  })
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` listener may get called multiple times. That is expected behavior, and your code should be ready to handle it. This means the code essentially has to be idempotent: calling it multiple times should have a single well-defined result.

For you that seems to be that you want a single user-specific document, even if your `onAuthStateChanged` listener gets called multiple times. An easy way to accomplish this is to use the user's UID as the document ID.

The code for that looks something like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
      FirstName: firstName,
      Middle_Name: middleName,
      Last_Name: lastName,
      Email: email,
    }).then(function() {
      console.log('data successfully added');
    }};
  } else {
    console.log('No user signed in');
  } 
})
```

I noticed that you attach the listener in a click handler. Whenever you attach a listener, immediately think of when that listener will be removed. With only the code you shared, if the user clicks twice, you'll end up with two listeners.

Comment: Hello Thank you again I have been trying to give you an up vote and it says I need a specific status to visually count